# I want a custom conditional formatting to fill a color for a cell depending on the number value after the decimal point

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am entering both positive and negative numbers in a column and want a way to identify them without an extra column for example -100.03 or -250.1 or 100.015. in this example I am listing moneyline betting odds and want to use the .1 to identify inside distance and .03 to mean over 3 rounds, and .015 to mean over 1.5 rounds. This will give me the type of prop bet even though I just have the number entered without the need for an extra column to identify it. I was thinking about regular expressions but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any range structure. But the decimal-only portion of any number can be found this way:

=*number* - INT(*number*)

So if your numbers in question were in A2:A, the CF custom formula might look like this:

```
=A2-INT(A2)=.03
```

Comment: When i enter a negative number which most are. it returns .97 is there a workaround for this like maybe =SQRT(A2 ^2)-INT(SQRT(A2^2))=.03 or perhaps you have another solution? How would I write a custom conditional format function to color red all such cells from a range  D3:D114? would I just insert D3:D114 in the position of A2 or would I have to use an array formula of some type.

Comment: Again, you haven't provided any context. I assume that every negative number you enter doesn't return .97, for instance. However, applying a custom CF rule to range D3:D114, you can try this: =ABS(D3)-ABS(INT(D3))=.03 [You only need to include the first cell in a range within the formula; the rest is extrapolated from that.]